# Is there support for multiple feign.Client beans within Spring

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

Some context

The project is a spring boot application (v 2.3.12) using spring-cloud-openfeign-core (v 2.2.8) to make REST requests.

The service has 2 clients

- one that needs to make REST requests using a proxy
- one that needs to make REST request without a proxy

I'm unable to get both client to work simultaneously, i.e. have requests work for both proxied and non-proxied resources.

Is it possible to use different configuration files to support this, I have tried something like this

Configuration class X

```
@bean
public Client client1() {
    return new Client.Default(null, null);
}
```

Configuration class Y

```
@bean
public Client client2() {
    return new Client.Proxied(null, null,
        new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("10.0.0.1", 8080)));
}
```

Feign interface code looks something like this

```
@Service
@FeignClient(name = "service1", url = "internal-url", configuration = X.class)
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
public interface serviceClient1 {

    @PostMapping(value = "/v1/path}")
    Response1 update(@RequestBody Request1 request1);
}

@Service
@FeignClient(name = "service2", url = "external-url", configuration = Y.class)
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
public interface serviceClient2 {

    @PostMapping(value = "/v1/path}")
    Response2 update(@RequestBody Request2 request2);
}
```

It seems only one of the client beans is used when making requests.

Comment: Please edit the post and add code of your service class where you are injecting Client object

Comment: Your configuration classes X and Y should not be annotated with @Configuration. Is it annotated with @Configuration?